# Unexpected changes on my account today, why?

Tags: support, profile-page

Today, I got changes on my SO account without explanation:

- My name changed to an alias I am used to take online, but never used in SO.
- My icon avatar was reset
- I got notified of all my badges again
- Some 20 points appeared without explanation to my reputation.

Why those changes appeared and where my new alias come from?

Comment: for the last point.. you got a couple of upvotes to a post.. https://stackoverflow.com/users/903651/escain?tab=reputation

Comment: Your account was merged; *two* newer accounts merged into this one.

Comment: And both this account and one of the merged accounts used this alias. The reputation is the merged amount earned by the 3 accounts combined (minus any cross voting, if there was any). I have found a Google Cache of your account that did not use this alias, which has the avatar image too; did you want that too?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks for your answer. I may add my avatar and name myself, that is not an issue. I wanted to understand the origin of this change. Is that something that SO is doing automatically, based on what is the match decided?

Comment: @Escain: this merge was executed manually, by a community manager. That *usually* means there was an explicit request to do so, but with the other two accounts deleted I can't see if any requests were raised. I've pinged the CM in question.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I performed this merge earlier today. I went over a support ticket you'd submitted (still not handled), and since it involved log-in issues and the email addresses matched, I just merged the two unregistered accounts into this one, to make sure that's out of the way and definitely not a cause for the issues being reported.

Comment: I have not made any request to merge my account, to be honest, I did not know about any other account and I am using this one for some 5-6 years now. I am not blaming as it is not an issue, but the guy who made the request will probably not be happy.

Comment: A request about log in issues with Area51 was submitted from one of the addresses used as a log in credential for your account on December 13th — was that not you? It was also signed with the same user name this profile had before I  performed the merge.

Comment: Ohh! So you suggest the login issue in Area51 was related with this credential corruption? now it make sense. Thanks you.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related, but stray unregistered accounts _can_ cause some issues with logging in. We're still looking into your request, though ;)

Comment: Seem the login issue is solved now.

Comment: Awesome, I'll just archive the pending support request, then ;)

Comment: Why is it that Area 51 has so many login issues? Also is auth different on superUser?

Comment: @NH. must be because Area 51 is Top Secret